# How to assign a unique key when using state.concat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react redux. I am trying to assign a unique key instead of it going in order by numbers like 0,1,2,3

Currently this is what I have when using state.concat

```
export const orders = (state = [],action)=> {


    const  {type,payload} = action;


        switch(type) {

            case "NEW_ORDER" :

            const {new_order} = payload;




                const new_state =  state.concat(new_order);
                console.log(new_state);


                return new_state;


        }

        return state


}
```

This is what i get in return

```
0: {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBfQItBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yIeB6B", …}
1: {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJtBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2NeB", …}
2: {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJEOBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2B6B", …}
3: {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJEOQItFOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yB", …}

instead i would like to have 



2938: {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJEOQItBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yIoNeB6B", …}
3942: {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJEOQItBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yIoNeB6B", …}
3932: {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJEOQItBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yIoNeB6B", …}
3939: {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJEOQItBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yIoNeB6B", …}

Any help would be really appreciated!
```

Comment: Those are array indices, not ids. Arrays are 0-indexed. What are you trying to do, add a unique identifier for when the new order element is added to state?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your item to have a unique id **in this session** then you can do the following:

```
//IIFE creating id
export const id = ((id) => () => id++)(1);
//in your reducer you imported the id function
const new_state = state.concat({ ...new_order, id: id() });
```

That works when your state is recreated when you refresh your page. If you persist your state (like with redux persist) then save the id counter in state and increment it every time you use it to assign an id to something.

If the orders are saved in a database then use that to create an id for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```js
state = [{store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBfQItBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yIeB6B"}
 ,{store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJtBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2NeB"}
 ,{store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJEOBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2B6B"},{store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBf1HJEOQItFOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yB"}]



new_order = {store_id: "1", company_id: "1", customer_id: "90694", trans_id: "pm_1I3kFGBfQItBHB4FOMI", merchant_customer_id: "cus_If4OD2yIeB6B"}

 new_state =  state.concat({...new_order,trans_id: 'Assign New ID', merchant_customer_id:'Assign New ID'});


console.log(new_state)
```